# Как из DataGridView получить в textBox номер колонки?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Задача: На нашей форме есть `DataGridView` и несколько, к примеру пять `textBox`.
Нужно выбирая мышкой ячейки `DataGridView` получать номер колонки в каждом `textBox`-е.

```
private DataGridViewCell clickedCell; //Переменная куда будет записываться координаты ячейки DataGridView
 string ctr;//Событие при клике на поле дата грида
    private void dataGridView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    { 
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            DataGridView.HitTestInfo hit = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            if (hit.Type == DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell)//производим проверку является ли событие от ячейки
            {
                clickedCell=
                   dataGridView1.Rows[hit.RowIndex].Cells[hit.ColumnIndex];
                ctr = Convert.ToString(clickedCell.ColumnIndex);
            }
        }           
    }
    //Событие при нажатии на поле textBox с именем Name
    private void textBoxName_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        //нужно вызвать событие dataGridView1_MouseClick
           textBoxName.Text = Convert.ToString(ctr);  
    }
```

Comment: В чём заключается ваш вопрос ? `dataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex`

Comment: Вопрос заключается в том, как написать код чтобы пользователь нажимая на колонки (ячейки)  DataGridView, смог выбирать необходимые колонки загруженной таблицы, для формирования новой таблицы. Другими словами нужно создать новую таблицу, на основе уже загруженной, для дальнейшей работы с ней (например передачи в БД ...).

Answer (score 0):

```
rowIndex = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex; //вытаскиваем индекс
textBoxName.Text = rowIndex.ToString(); //отправляем в textbox
```

По C# очень подробная документация. Взято отсюда: [DataGridViewCell.RowIndex Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.rowindex(v=vs.110).aspx). Там и `RowIndex` и `ColumnIndex` есть

Comment: `ColumnIndex`, ТС надо столбец.

Answer (score 0):

*Нужно выбирая мышкой ячейки `DataGridView` получать номер колонки*.
Пологаю номер колонки это его координаты?Если так то у `DataGridView` есть евент по имени `CellClick` можно использовать скажем вот так!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Control item in this.Controls)
        {
            if (item.GetType().Name == "TextBox")//получаем все TextBox-и
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(item.Text))//проверяем наличия текста
                {
                    item.Text = $"({e.RowIndex},{e.ColumnIndex})";
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```